# HP wireless keyboard

Tags: keyboard

The shift key on my keyboard is not working right. If I use shift plus another key combination (i, t) I will get a window that looks like DOS of programming, or open a duplicate tab. With other letters, it just may not work.
The cap lock key will work to give me caps, but that becomes quit tedious. 
I have tried the following:
1. take the batteries out to try and reset
2. replace the batteries
3. uninstall from device manager and restart
4. Tried control + shift (and repeated this)
5. just restarting the computer

Nothing has worked. I suspect that I inadvertently hit 2 buttons and which put the keyboard in some other mode, but I don't know what 2 keystrokes I could have made or how to restore the keyboard.

Anyone out there have any suggestions? I have had to resort to using a wired keyboard, which is ok, but wireless is just so much better

Answer (score 1):

Facts:

- The problem is not with the computer, as the wired keyboard functions correctly.
- Whatever mode you put the wireless keyboard into is cancelled when it is
  powered down.

Therefore I highly suspect the keyboard of having issues.

What you can do:

- Clean the keyboard thoroughly (and carefully)
- Try it on another computer
- Try another wireless keyboard.

This will help you decide whether it is time to replace that keyboard or not.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestions. Hopefully, I do not have to replace the keyboard, but I know I can't use it the way it is functioning now. I just find it a little hard to believe  it is an issue with the keys as both shift keys are acting the same. But it is what it is. Electronics can be frustrating when they don't work right.